# OpenCV C++. Quickly compute confusion matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, roc, confusion-matrix

What is the preferred way to compute a confusion matrix with OpenCV and C++?

Starting from:

```
int TP = 0,FP = 0,FN = 0,TN = 0;
cv::Mat truth(60,60, CV_8UC1);
cv::Mat detections(60,60, CV_8UC1);

this->loadResults(truth, detections); // loadResults(cv::Mat& t, cv::Mat& d);
```

I tried a few different options like:

1. Direct Calls:

   ```
   for(int r = 0; r < detections.rows; ++r)
   for(int c = 0; c < detections.cols; ++c)
   {
       int d,t;
       d = detection.at<unsigned char>(r,c);
       t = truth.at<unsigned char>(r,c);
       if(d&&t)    ++TP;
       if(d&&!t)   ++FP;
       if(!d&&t)   ++FN;
       if(!d&&!t)  ++TN;
   }
   ```
2. RAM heavy matrix logic:

   ```
   {
       cv::Mat truePos = detection.mul(truth);
       TP = cv::countNonZero(truePos)
   }
   {
       cv::Mat falsePos = detection.mul(~truth);
       FP = cv::countNonZero(falsePos )
   }
   {
       cv::Mat falseNeg = truth.mul(~detection);
       FN = cv::countNonZero(falseNeg )
   }
   {
       cv::Mat trueNeg = (~truth).mul(~detection);
       TN = cv::countNonZero(trueNeg )
   }
   ```
3. forEach:

   ```
   auto lambda = [&, truth,TP,FP,FN,TN](unsigned char d, const int pos[]){
       cv::Point2i pt(pos[1], pos[0]);
       char t = truth.at<unsigned char>(pt);
       if(d&&t)    ++TP;
       if(d&&!t)   ++FP;
       if(!d&&t)   ++FN;
       if(!d&&!t)  ++TN;
   };
   detection.forEach(lambda);
   ```

But is there a standard way of doing it? I might have missed a simple function in OpenCV docs.

p.s. I used VS2010 x64;

Comment: You tagged your question with [roc], are you after the ROC curve or the confusion matrix?

Comment: @AlexandrCrit I'm not aware of any specific function in OpenCV to do this, but (with the last edit) I got it to run at around 2ms for a 4096x4096 input on an i7-4930k... is that quick enough? ;)

Comment: @Calimo, i use confusion matrix to agragate data for ROC curve for quite large (120GB of tif's up to 1,2GB per scene) satellite imagery test set. So i calculate confusion several times for different threshold of my resolving rule.

Comment: @AlexandrCrit then don't calculate the confusion matrix at all. You can sort the data by increasing value and calculate the positives and negatives directly. I have some R code doing that, you can use it as a starting point: https://github.com/xrobin/pROC/blob/master/R/roc.utils.R#L44

Comment: @Calimo, I have an awful lot of data. I changed it a bit latter to store data distibution in histograms in bins based on probability that pixel is an object, and compute ROC point by point from hists at a latter date using data streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, none of the three.

Before we begin, let's define a simple struct to hold our results:

```
struct result_t
{
    int TP;
    int FP;
    int FN;
    int TN;
};
```

This will let us wrap each implementation in a function with following signature, in order to simplify testing and performance evaluation. (Note that I use `cv::Mat1b` to make it explicit we want only mats of type `CV_8UC1`:

```
result_t conf_mat_x(cv::Mat1b truth, cv::Mat1b detections);
```

I will measure performance with randomly generated data of size 4096 x 4096.

I'm using MSVS2013 64bit with OpenCV 3.1 here. Sorry, don't have a MSVS2010 set up with OpenCV ready for testing this, and the timing code using c++11, so you may need to modify that in order to compile.

---

### Variant 1 -- "Direct Calls"

Updated version of your code looks like this:

```
result_t conf_mat_1a(cv::Mat1b truth, cv::Mat1b detections)
{
    CV_Assert(truth.size == detections.size);

    result_t result = { 0 };
    for (int r(0); r < detections.rows; ++r) {
        for (int c(0); c < detections.cols; ++c) {
            int d(detections.at<uchar>(r, c));
            int t(truth.at<uchar>(r, c));
            if (d&&t) { ++result.TP; }
            if (d&&!t) { ++result.FP; }
            if (!d&&t) { ++result.FN; }
            if (!d&&!t) { ++result.TN; }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

*Performance and results:*

```
#0:     min=120.017     mean=123.258    TP=4192029      FP=4195489      TN=4195118      FN=4194580      Total=16777216
```

The main problem here is that this (especially with VS2010) is unlikely to get auto-vectorized, so will be rather slow. Taking advantage of SIMD could potentially allow up to an order of magnitude speedup. Additionally repeated calls to `cv::Mat::at` can add some overhead as well.

There really isn't much to gain here, we should be able to do better.

---

### Variant 2 -- "RAM Heavy"

*Code:*

```
result_t conf_mat_2a(cv::Mat1b truth, cv::Mat1b detections)
{
    CV_Assert(truth.size == detections.size);

    result_t result = { 0 };
    {
        cv::Mat truePos = detections.mul(truth);
        result.TP = cv::countNonZero(truePos);
    }
    {
        cv::Mat falsePos = detections.mul(~truth);
        result.FP = cv::countNonZero(falsePos);
    }
    {
        cv::Mat falseNeg = truth.mul(~detections);
        result.FN = cv::countNonZero(falseNeg);
    }
    {
        cv::Mat trueNeg = (~truth).mul(~detections);
        result.TN = cv::countNonZero(trueNeg);
    }

    return result;
}
```

*Performance and results:*

```
#1:     min=63.993      mean=68.674     TP=4192029      FP=4195489      TN=4195118      FN=4194580      Total=16777216
```

This is already about twice as fast, even though there's a lot of unnecessary work being done.

Multiplication (with saturation) seems an overkill -- a `bitwise_and` will do the job as well and can potentially shave off a little bit of time.

A huge overhead is imposed by a number of redundant matrix allocations. Instead of allocating a new matrix for each of `truePos`, `falsePos`, `falseNeg` and `trueNeg`, we can reuse the same `cv::Mat` for all 4 cases. Since the shape and data type will always be the same, this means only 1 allocation will happen instead of 4.

---

*Code:*

```
result_t conf_mat_2b(cv::Mat1b truth, cv::Mat1b detections)
{
    CV_Assert(truth.size == detections.size);

    result_t result = { 0 };

    cv::Mat temp;
    cv::bitwise_and(detections, truth, temp);
    result.TP = cv::countNonZero(temp);
    cv::bitwise_and(detections, ~truth, temp);
    result.FP = cv::countNonZero(temp);
    cv::bitwise_and(~detections, truth, temp);
    result.FN = cv::countNonZero(temp);
    cv::bitwise_and(~detections, ~truth, temp);
    result.TN = cv::countNonZero(temp);

    return result;
}
```

*Performance and results:*

```
#2:     min=50.995      mean=52.440     TP=4192029      FP=4195489      TN=4195118      FN=4194580      Total=16777216
```

Time needed has been reduced by ~20% compared to `conf_mat_2a`.

Next, notice that you're calculating `~truth` and `~detections` twice. Hence, we can eliminate the operations along with 2 additional allocations by reusing them as well.

NB: The memory usage won't change -- we needed 3 temporary arrays before, and that's still the case.

---

*Code:*

```
result_t conf_mat_2c(cv::Mat1b truth, cv::Mat1b detections)
{
    CV_Assert(truth.size == detections.size);

    result_t result = { 0 };

    cv::Mat inv_truth(~truth);
    cv::Mat inv_detections(~detections);

    cv::Mat temp;
    cv::bitwise_and(detections, truth, temp);
    result.TP = cv::countNonZero(temp);
    cv::bitwise_and(detections, inv_truth, temp);
    result.FP = cv::countNonZero(temp);
    cv::bitwise_and(inv_detections, truth, temp);
    result.FN = cv::countNonZero(temp);
    cv::bitwise_and(inv_detections, inv_truth, temp);
    result.TN = cv::countNonZero(temp);

    return result;
}
```

*Performance and results:*

```
#3:     min=37.997      mean=38.569     TP=4192029      FP=4195489      TN=4195118      FN=4194580      Total=16777216
```

Time needed has been reduced by ~40% compared to `conf_mat_2a`.

There's still potential for improvement. Let's make some observations.

- `element_count == rows * cols` where `rows` and `cols` represent the height and width of the `cv::Mat` (we can use `cv::Mat::total()`).
- `TP + FP + FN + TN == element_count` since each element belongs to exactly 1 of the 4 sets.
- `positive_count` is the number of non-zero elements in `detections`.
- `negative_count` is the number of zero elements in `detections`.
- `positive_count + negative_count == element_count` since each element belongs to exactly 1 of the 2 sets
- `TP + FP == positive_count`
- `TN + FN == negative_count`

Using this information we can calculate `TN` using simple arithmetics, thus eliminating one `bitwise_and` and one `countNonZero`. We can similarly calculate `FP`, eliminating another `bitwise_and`, and using the second `countNonZero` to calculate `positive_count` instead.

Since we eliminated both uses of `inv_truth`, we can drop it as well.

NB: The memory usage has been reduced -- we now only have 2 temporary arrays.

---

*Code:*

```
result_t conf_mat_2d(cv::Mat1b truth, cv::Mat1b detections)
{
    CV_Assert(truth.size == detections.size);

    result_t result = { 0 };

    cv::Mat1b inv_detections(~detections);
    int positive_count(cv::countNonZero(detections));
    int negative_count(static_cast<int>(truth.total()) - positive_count);

    cv::Mat1b temp;
    cv::bitwise_and(truth, detections, temp);
    result.TP = cv::countNonZero(temp);
    result.FP = positive_count - result.TP;

    cv::bitwise_and(truth, inv_detections, temp);
    result.FN = cv::countNonZero(temp);
    result.TN = negative_count - result.FN;

    return result;
}
```

*Performance and results:*

```
#4:     min=22.494      mean=22.831     TP=4192029      FP=4195489      TN=4195118      FN=4194580      Total=16777216
```

Time needed has been reduced by ~65% compared to `conf_mat_2a`.

Finally, since we only need `inv_detections` once, we can reuse `temp` to store it, getting rid of one more allocation, and further reducing memory footprint.

NB: The memory usage has been reduced -- we now only have 1 temporary array.

---

*Code:*

```
result_t conf_mat_2e(cv::Mat1b truth, cv::Mat1b detections)
{
    CV_Assert(truth.size == detections.size);

    result_t result = { 0 };

    int positive_count(cv::countNonZero(detections));
    int negative_count(static_cast<int>(truth.total()) - positive_count);

    cv::Mat1b temp;
    cv::bitwise_and(truth, detections, temp);
    result.TP = cv::countNonZero(temp);
    result.FP = positive_count - result.TP;

    cv::bitwise_not(detections, temp);
    cv::bitwise_and(truth, temp, temp);
    result.FN = cv::countNonZero(temp);
    result.TN = negative_count - result.FN;

    return result;
}
```

*Performance and results:*

```
#5:     min=16.999      mean=17.391     TP=4192029      FP=4195489      TN=4195118      FN=4194580      Total=16777216
```

Time needed has been reduced by ~72% compared to `conf_mat_2a`.

---

### Variant 3 -- "forEach with lambda"

This again suffers from the same issue as variant 1, namely it's unlikely to get vectorized, so it will be relatively slow.

The major issue with your implementation is the fact that `forEach` runs the function in parallel on multiple slices of the input, and there's lack of any synchronization. The current implementation returns incorrect results.

However, the idea of parallelizing could be applied with some effort to the best of Variant 2.

---

### Variant 4 -- "Parallel"

Let's improve on `conf_mat_2e` by taking advantage of [`cv::parallel_for_`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d7/dff/tutorial_how_to_use_OpenCV_parallel_for_.html). The simplest way to distribute the load between worker threads is to do it on a row-by-row basis.

We can avoid the need for synchronization by sharing an intermediate `cv::Mat3i` which will hold `TP`, `FP`, and `FN` for each row (recall that `TN` can be calculated from the other 3 at the end). Since each row is only processed by a single worker thread, we don't need to synchronize. Once all the rows have been processed, a simple `cv::sum` will give us a total `TP`, `FP`, and `FN`. The `TN` is then calculated.

NB: We can again reduce memory requirements -- we need a one buffer spanning a single row for each worker. Additionally, we need `3 * rows` integers to store the intermediate results.

*Code:*

```
class ParallelConfMat : public cv::ParallelLoopBody
{
public:
    enum
    {
        TP = 0
        , FP = 1
        , FN = 2
    };

    ParallelConfMat(cv::Mat1b& truth, cv::Mat1b& detections, cv::Mat3i& result)
        : truth_(truth)
        , detections_(detections)
        , result_(result)
    {
    }

    ParallelConfMat& operator=(ParallelConfMat const&)
    {
        return *this;
    };

    virtual void operator()(cv::Range const& range) const
    {
        cv::Mat1b temp;
        for (int r(range.start); r < range.end; r++) {
            cv::Mat1b detections(detections_.row(r));
            cv::Mat1b truth(truth_.row(r));
            cv::Vec3i& result(result_.at<cv::Vec3i>(r));

            int positive_count(cv::countNonZero(detections));
            int negative_count(static_cast<int>(truth.total()) - positive_count);

            cv::bitwise_and(truth, detections, temp);
            result[TP] = cv::countNonZero(temp);
            result[FP] = positive_count - result[TP];

            cv::bitwise_not(detections, temp);
            cv::bitwise_and(truth, temp, temp);
            result[FN] = cv::countNonZero(temp);
        }
    }

private:
    cv::Mat1b& truth_;
    cv::Mat1b& detections_;
    cv::Mat3i& result_; // TP, FP, FN per row
};

result_t conf_mat_4(cv::Mat1b truth, cv::Mat1b detections)
{
    CV_Assert(truth.size == detections.size);

    result_t result = { 0 };

    cv::Mat3i partial_results(truth.rows, 1);
    cv::parallel_for_(cv::Range(0, truth.rows)
        , ParallelConfMat(truth, detections, partial_results));
    cv::Scalar reduced_results = cv::sum(partial_results);

    result.TP = static_cast<int>(reduced_results[ParallelConfMat::TP]);
    result.FP = static_cast<int>(reduced_results[ParallelConfMat::FP]);
    result.FN = static_cast<int>(reduced_results[ParallelConfMat::FN]);
    result.TN = static_cast<int>(truth.total()) - result.TP - result.FP - result.FN;

    return result;
}
```

*Performance and results:*

```
#6:     min=1.496       mean=1.966      TP=4192029      FP=4195489      TN=4195118      FN=4194580      Total=16777216
```

This is running on 6 core CPU with HT enabled (i.e. 12 threads).

The runtime has been reduce by ~97.5% compared to `conf_mat_2a`.

It may be the case that for very small inputs, this may be sub-optimal. The ideal implementation may be a combination of some of those approaches, delegating based on the input size.

---

*Test code:*

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>

using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::microseconds;

struct result_t
{
    int TP;
    int FP;
    int FN;
    int TN;
};

/******** PASTE all the conf_mat_xx functions here *********/

int main()
{
    int ROWS(4 * 1024), COLS(4 * 1024), ITERS(32);

    cv::Mat1b truth(ROWS, COLS);
    cv::randu(truth, 0, 2);
    truth *= 255;

    cv::Mat1b detections(ROWS, COLS);
    cv::randu(detections, 0, 2);
    detections *= 255;

    typedef result_t(*conf_mat_fn)(cv::Mat1b, cv::Mat1b);
    struct test_info
    {
        conf_mat_fn fn;
        std::vector<double> d;
        result_t r;
    };
    std::vector<test_info> info;
    info.push_back({ conf_mat_1a });
    info.push_back({ conf_mat_2a });
    info.push_back({ conf_mat_2b });
    info.push_back({ conf_mat_2c });
    info.push_back({ conf_mat_2d });
    info.push_back({ conf_mat_2e });
    info.push_back({ conf_mat_4 });

    // Warm-up
    for (int n(0); n < info.size(); ++n) {
        info[n].fn(truth, detections);
    }

    for (int i(0); i < ITERS; ++i) {
        for (int n(0); n < info.size(); ++n) {
            high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
            info[n].r = info[n].fn(truth, detections);
            high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
            info[n].d.push_back(static_cast<double>(duration_cast<microseconds>(t2 - t1).count()) / 1000.0);
        }
    }

    for (int n(0); n < info.size(); ++n) {
        std::cout << "#" << n << ":"
            << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3)
            << "\tmin=" << *std::min_element(info[n].d.begin(), info[n].d.end())
            << "\tmean=" << cv::mean(info[n].d)[0]
            << "\tTP=" << info[n].r.TP
            << "\tFP=" << info[n].r.FP
            << "\tTN=" << info[n].r.TN
            << "\tFN=" << info[n].r.FN
            << "\tTotal=" << (info[n].r.TP + info[n].r.FP + info[n].r.TN + info[n].r.FN)
            << "\n";
    }
}
```

---

Performance and results from MSVS2015, Win64, OpenCV 3.4.3:

```
#0:     min=119.797     mean=121.769    TP=4192029      FP=4195489      TN=4195118      FN=4194580      Total=16777216
#1:     min=64.130      mean=65.086     TP=4192029      FP=4195489      TN=4195118      FN=4194580      Total=16777216
#2:     min=51.152      mean=51.758     TP=4192029      FP=4195489      TN=4195118      FN=4194580      Total=16777216
#3:     min=37.781      mean=38.357     TP=4192029      FP=4195489      TN=4195118      FN=4194580      Total=16777216
#4:     min=22.329      mean=22.637     TP=4192029      FP=4195489      TN=4195118      FN=4194580      Total=16777216
#5:     min=17.029      mean=17.297     TP=4192029      FP=4195489      TN=4195118      FN=4194580      Total=16777216
#6:     min=1.827       mean=2.017      TP=4192029      FP=4195489      TN=4195118      FN=4194580      Total=16777216
```

Comment: My further experiments showed in general the same results, except for some strange differences: 1st in debug build #0 is the slowest variant but not by much (380ms vs 320ms against #1, and 102ms mean for forEach at 9M pixels), but in release build in suddenly is almost as fast as forEach (16ms vs 15ms mean for 9M pixels, but dispersion of results is much higher for #0). BTW, i have builded openCV 3.3.0 from sources and enables OpenMP in both OpenCV and my test projects. Docs say that for each should be run multithreded this openmp "on".

Comment: BTW, measuring debug builds is not very useful, since there's no optimization done.

Comment: Only for debug purposes, some times you just have to run your classifier evaluations, while you debugging some other stuff. f.ex. evolution algorithms that use your classifiers.

Comment: Ah, good point. In that case, if you're not debugging this part, shove it into a separate module and override the optimization settings just for that.